# Updating Schema in MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I have a user schema model where the `address` field is(should) be populated via the address schema model. To update the address schema I've passed in the request body and have populated the `userId` field by pulling the users' id from the `req.user`. I'm able to add new entries to the address field but when I look at the user model in Atlas, it's not populated.

My assumption was that it would automatically populate that based on the user's ID but this doesnt seem to be the case.. Am i going about this incorrectly?

**route:**

```
const addAddress = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    // Destruct Request
    const { name, street, city, state, zipcode } = req.body;

    // Define User ID
    const user = req.user.id;

    const addUserAddress = await User.findById(user, (error, address) => {
      if (error) {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ success: false, message: 'An unexpected error occurred.' });
      }

      let newAddress = new Address({
        _userId: user,
        name,
        street,
        city,
        state,
        zipcode,
      });

      newAddress.save((err0r) => {
        if (error) {
          return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ success: false, message: 'An unexpected error occurred.' });
        }
      });
    });
    res.json(addUserAddress);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error adding an address, please try again.');
  }
};
```

**address model:**

```
const AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _userId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  zipcode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
});

const Address = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);

exports.Address = Address;
```

**user model:**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  address: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Address',
    },
  ],
  ...
});
```

Comment: By the way, I don't see where in the above code you're pushing the new address into the address array on the User model.

You have to save the new address, get saved addresses ID (this is returned on save). Then do something like foundUser.address.push(savedAddress._id); foundUser.save()

You also have err0r in your code rather than "error"

Answer (score 0):

The ID gets inserted, but the information doesn't automatically populate. In order to populate the information you have to do something like this...

```
const usersWithAddress = await User.find({}).populate("address", "city state zip", Address) // Pass in the Address model as the 3rd argument.
```

Populate will work without the Address model, but I've had issues in the past at times when I didn't pass it in.